# Lex and Yacc Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, yacc, lex

How to set up lex and Yacc with Xcode 4? What custom script should I write in the Build Rules to do that?

I have one lex file abc.l and one yacc file cba.y both placed in the same directory as that of other project source files.
parser.ymm

```
%{
    #include<iostream>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include "querystructure.h"
    using namespace std;
    static int col_id = 0;


extern void yyerror (char* message);
extern int yylex ();
%}
```

lexer.l/lexer.lm

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"

%}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like all you need to do is to rename your `*.y` file to `*.ym`:

[I am extremely pleased that all I had to do was make the suffix to the yacc file be .ym instead of .y to get Xcode to do all the right things.](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/282676-bison-yacc-with-objective.html)

I have not tried this, but the linked post suggests that XCode has enough smarts built into it in order to deal with parser generators "automagically".

Comment: The lexer is not getting included...I am getting the following error:y.tab.c:1327:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'yylex';

Comment: @JuliusCanute This is a complete shot in the dark, but try renaming your `*.l` file to `*.lm` and see if it works.

Comment: Still getting the following error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "yylex()", referenced from:
      yyparse() in y.tab.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: @JuliusCanute This is probably related to your grammar/lexer files. Could you update the question with the top portion of both? The only parts of interest are between `%{` and `}%`

Comment: @JuliusCanute It's getting late in my time zone, I wouldn't be able to reply till tomorrow. Take a look at the answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596239/simple-flex-bison-c) to see if you may be missing an `extern "C"` declaration somewhere.